# How to show privacy policy URL and terms of service URL inside the Google one-tap UI for new users?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-identity

A few days ago, I noticed **googleyolo client library** was showing this message:

> An UI change targeting on 5/18/2018 will show relying party's privacy
>   policy URL and terms of service URL inside the one-tap UI for new
>   users. If enabled, SHOW_RP_TOS can be found in
>   GOOGLE_ONETAP_EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURES array. To try this feature, append
>   '?e=1723232' to googleyolo client library URL.

When using https://smartlock.google.com/client?e=1723232 as `googleyolo` client library URL, I see no change in the one-tap UI.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to show Terms of Service URL in one-tap UI?

Comment: This should be available for everyone now, let us know if it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that experiment didn't work. We'll be rolling out the changes this week, so you'll be able to see them. If you want to see the change on your site before it is rolled out, there is a google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/yolo-web-testers) you can join and you'll see the notice.

Comment: Yes please provide me the necessary information to see this change on the site.

Comment: Join this group to see the new UI: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/yolo-web-testers (make sure you reset any grants for the site you are visiting at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions )

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available for all sites now. If you don't see the links in the UI, check the following:

- ensure you have supplied a privacy policy and/or terms of service link in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_) for the OAuth project / client ID that you using in the API requests (under "consent screen" in the credentials section). Refer to the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/get-started#get_your_google_api_client_id) for background.
- verify that the active Google Account(s) has not already granted access to name/email address info via previous usage of one-tap or Google Sign-In button. You can check and reset this at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Also note that if you have multiple active accounts, you will need to select one before the blue button and legal text are shown. Please leave a comment if you have trouble.

Comment: thank you very very much! i search this solution for 2 month!