# Google One-Tap signin missing legal & terms of service section

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-one-tap

i have initiate `google one-tap` login on our site
it seems that the section of `privacy policy` & `terms of service` are missing.

how can i show them?

our one-tap popup:
[image]

Example of one-tap popups from other sites on the internet:
[image]
[image]

**our implementation based on:**
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference

and look like this:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<script>
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: googleClientId,
        callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
        context: 'signin',
    });
    google.accounts.id.prompt();
</script>
```

**our `GCP` application**
*`OAuth consent screen` tab*:

- all fields were filled and also `app domain` section:

  - `application home page` (https://<our_domain>)
  - `application privacy policy link` (https://<our_domain>/privacy_policy)
  - `application terms of service link` (https://<our_domain>/term_of_use)
- Our Google `application status`:  `Verified` & `In production`
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found the answer here:
[How to show privacy policy URL and terms of service URL inside the Google one-tap UI for new users?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51716012/2591785)

> - ensure you have supplied a privacy policy and/or terms of service link
>   in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_) for the OAuth project / client ID that
>   you using in the API requests (under "consent screen" in the
>   credentials section). Refer to the [Getting Started guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/get-started#get_your_google_api_client_id) for
>   background.
> - verify that the active Google Account(s) has not already granted
>   access to name/email address info via previous usage of one-tap or
>   Google Sign-In button. You can check and reset this at
>   https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

as wrote there:

1. navigate to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions
2. find & delete the site from the list
3. navigate to your site, and see one-tap popup include legal & terms of service